# HTTP request in SessionEnded event not firing

Tags: c#

I'd like to make a HTTP request in on system shutdown, log off or reboot. For that I implemented a handler for `SystemEvents.SessionEnded` event:

// main

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded += new SessionEndedEventHandler(Shutdown.ProcessExit);
```

// Shutdown class

```
public static void ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e){
  File.WriteAllText("path","ProcessExit fired")
  string jsonString = "{}";
  string url= "localurl";
  using (var client = new HttpClient()){
    StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
  }
}
```

To my surprise, the http request never fires as evident in server access logs. What is the correct approach to make a HTTP request while computer is being shut down? I can confirm that the event does get fired, because writing on ProcessExit is successful, so the problem is related strictly to making http request.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Solution that I tested again and again and it works perfectly is creating a scheduled Task on Event Id 1074 and Start the Custom application :

Add new trigger on an Event type **Basic**:

**Log**: System

**Source**: User32

**EventID**: 1074

And put your application in actions.

Comment: Thank you for stpping by XAMT. I've tested this approach but unfortunately the event is not being fired on restart or log off. That is, the app in actions is never run. If I run it manually in Task Scheduler, it sends the http request.

Comment: @RobertSegdewick; Windows `Logoff` Event ID is: 4647 and 6006 are for `Restart`. So add these events in trigger Tab. Also if your application needs `Administrator Privileges` Check it in the first tab.

Comment: tested for shutdown. Event is not triggered.

Comment: @RobertSegdewick; Choose "Run Whether user is logged on or not" and check Run with highest privileges. Also, Choose the with OS.